# I can't update minecraft to 1.13 ios

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My Minecraft on my iPhone is still on the 1.12 edition and i would like to update it to 1.13 but I can't because it's not showing that I can update it. this is really annoying. please, can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

Minecraft Bedrock Edition is currently only on 1.12. The 1.13 update refers to the Beta version of the game.
To join Beta, you have to go to your app store and scroll down to the "Join Beta" section, and download the game as a Beta app. You will be unable to play multiplayer as long as you are enrolled in the Beta program.

Answer (score -2):

Are you updated to the latest iOS? Minecraft now requires iOS 8 or later. Also, your phone itself may be too old to run Minecraft. Update Aquatic is now over a year old, and there have been other updates since then, fyi.